# Cannot set propert 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I am trying to make a nutrition website which gives nutritional data in a tabled based on the amount of a food one eats.  I will type the amount of food I eat in an input box and push a button,  a caculation is run, and the number of macronutrients for the specific food is put into cells in a table.  I am in an elementary stage of writing this code so it is pretty basic and will eventually be more complicated, but I am stuck.

The code I have written works and puts the correct amount of macronutrients in the correct data cells, but the console says "Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined."  The error is on the last row of code in my for loop.  This error seems to render any other code I write after the for loop invalid.  Could someone explain why this error occurs and how I might correct my mistake?  My code is below.

**while this may not be the most efficient code to implement for what I am trying to accomplish, I would appreciate and answer to my specific question as opposed to only showing me completely different way to write the code.  Once my question is answered, any additional advice on stronger code writing (soley in JS, not Jquery) is certainly welcomed.  Thank you for your time.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="amount"></input>
    </td>
    <td class="carbs">
    </td>
    <td class="fiber">
    </td>
    <td class="protein">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="calc()">calculate</button>

<script>
var row = [];
var broccoli = [.5, .08, 1];

var amt = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");
var carbs = document.getElementsByClassName("carb");
var fiber = document.getElementsByClassName("fiber");
var protein = document.getElementsByClassName("protein");

var category = [carbs[0], fiber[0], protein[0]];

function calc() {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    row.splice(i, 0, broccoli[i]*amt[0].value);
    category[i].innerHTML = row[i].toFixed(2);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your for loop in calc is looping from 0 - 3. Both of your arrays only have 3 elements.

Comment: The elements class name is carbs, you are looking for carb

Comment: @Jecoms Thanks for the insight, changing the number 4 to 3 fixed it.

Comment: `innerHTML` is poor practice anyways, in the majority of cases.

Comment: @ndugger What is a better substitute for innerHTML?

Comment: @AndrewJones if you're just injecting text, use `textContent`. If you're adding elements, create an element using `document.createElement` and then append it via `appendChild`. The only time you should use `innerHTML` is if you get HTML from the server and need to put it on the page, but you have other bad code at that point that you should address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in the carbs class name. You are also looping 4 times when your  category and broccoli arrays only had three elements. It's safest to use the `.length` property of the array you're looping through.

```
<script>
    var row = [];
    var broccoli = [.5, .08, 1];

    var amt = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");
    var carbs = document.getElementsByClassName("carbs"); //typo
    var fiber = document.getElementsByClassName("fiber");
    var protein = document.getElementsByClassName("protein");

    var category = [carbs[0], fiber[0], protein[0]];

    function calc() {
      for (i = 0; i < category.length; i++){ // update limit to 3 or .length of array
        row.splice(i, 0, broccoli[i]*amt[0].value);
        category[i].innerHTML = row[i].toFixed(2);
      }
    }
</script>
```